# Network copy - transferring files from one server to another

Tags: networking, file-transfer, smb, copying

This question is very basic but something that I've been bothered by recently. Let's say there are two servers A & B in the same network as a workstation W running say Win 7. Now when I transfer files from A to B (which are either mounted on W or via Explorer), what is the data path of these files and what role does the workstation W play in this?

My assumption is that the data is transferred from A to B directly, via the switch they are plugged into. But what about the networking protocol that say Win 7 uses to mount these drives - does it affect the process at all?

Thanks in advance for any information on this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I believe TFTP is used if the servers are in the same network..

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand, but if I do, workstation W plays no role. Servers are just other computers. So what I'm seeing the question as is, "If I have three computers on a network, and transfer files between two of them, what role does the third play?" If that is the case, then the answer SHOULD be (barring strange networking!) "none".